# Json.net deserialization null guid case

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm deserializing an object using `Json.NET` that contains a private field of type Guid and a public property for that field. When the value for my `Guid` is null in my json I want to assign `Guid.Empty` to my field.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Guid property;
    public Guid Property
    {
        get { return property; }
        set 
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                property = Guid.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                property = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the `deserializer` wants to access the private field, cause I get this error when I try to deserialize:

> Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Guid'. Path
>   '[0].property', line 6, position 26.

How can I make it ignore the private field and use the public property instead?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Json.NET refuses to set a `null` value for a `Guid` because it is a non-nullable value type.  Try typing `(Guid)null` in the [Immediate Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx) and you will see an error message indicating that this conversion cannot be made in .Net.

To work around this, you have a couple of options:

1. Create a `Guid?` nullable proxy property.  It can be private if you desire as long as it has a [`[JsonProperty]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attribute:

   ```
   public class MyClass
   {
       [JsonIgnore]
       public Guid Property { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("Property")]
       Guid? NullableProperty { get { return Property == Guid.Empty ? null : (Guid?)Property; } set { Property = (value == null ? Guid.Empty : value.Value); } }
   }
   ```
2. Create a [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) that converts a `null` Json token to a default Guid value:

   ```
   public class NullToDefaultConverter<T> : JsonConverter where T : struct
   {
       public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
       {
           return objectType == typeof(T);
       }

       public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           var token = JToken.Load(reader);
           if (token == null || token.Type == JTokenType.Null)
               return default(T);
           return token.ToObject(objectType); // Deserialize using default serializer
       }

       // Return false instead if you don't want default values to be written as null
       public override bool CanWrite { get { return true; } }

       public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals((T)value, default(T)))
               writer.WriteNull();
           else
               writer.WriteValue(value);
       }
   }
   ```

   Then apply it to your type as follows:

   ```
   public class MyClass
   {
       [JsonConverter(typeof(NullToDefaultConverter<Guid>))]
       public Guid Property { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   Alternatively, you can apply the converter to all values of type `T` by adding the converter to [`JsonSerializerSettings.Converters`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Converters.htm).  And, to register such a converter globally, see e.g.*[How to set custom JsonSerializerSettings for Json.NET in MVC 4 Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13274625/3744182)* for Web API, *[Setting JsonConvert.DefaultSettings asp net core 2.0 not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46360651/3744182)* for ASP.NET Core or *[Registering a custom JsonConverter globally in Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19510532/3744182)* for a console app.

   If you do register the converter globally for a console app, you may need to disable it for recursive calls as shown in *[JSON.Net throws StackOverflowException when using [JsonConvert()]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29719509/3744182)*.
3. If you only need to **deserialize** a `null` value for a Guid and not re-serialize it as such, you can apply [`[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_NullValueHandling.htm) to the Guid property, and `null` values will ignored despite being invalid Guid values:

   ```cs
   public class MyClass
   {
       [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
       public Guid Property { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   Of course if you do this your Guid will be re-serialized as `"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"`.  To ameliorate that you could apply [`DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_DefaultValueHandling.htm) which will cause empty Guid values to be omitted during serialization:

   ```
   [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
   public Guid Property { get; set; }
   ```

   Note that if a [parameterized constructor](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConstructorAttribute.htm) called during deserialization has a non-nullable Guid argument with the same name, a different approach may be required.

Comment: Thank you! One question about the Null to default converter. Do I have to manually add the JsonConverter attribute to each field/property in my class or can I somehow add it for all the properties in the class ?

Comment: You can either add it to each property or register it for use globally in all classes.  See [Registering a custom JsonConverter in Json.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510532/registering-a-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net).

Comment: The 3rd option was exactly what I needed. Thank you for providing extensive answers for possible use cases.