Modelbinding in asp.net with newtonsoft
I am migrating a .NET Framework project to .NET 8 and I have an issue in difference in model binding and I can't find why it is behaving differently.
In both projects I am using Newtonsoft for JSON deserialization. I have a class Person with an Age property. If I do a Post with null as value for age there is a difference in behavior between both frameworks.
In .NET Framework it converts to 0 and the Name property is set to the correct value.
In .NET 8 it throws an exception.
I do understand the exception in .NET 8, I am more surprised it actually work in .NET Framework. Does .NET Framework set some extra deserialization properties, and if so what are they exactly ?
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

}

My controller (.NET Framework)
public class PersonController : ApiController
{
    public int Post([FromBody] Person person)
    {
        return person.Age;
    }
}

My controller .NET 8
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class PersonController : ControllerBase
{
     [HttpPost]
     public int Post([FromBody] Person person)
     {
         return person.Age;
     }
}

(Specifically for .NET 8 I add the newtonsoft serializer)
builder
    .Services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();

My json data I send
{
    "name": "test",
    "age": null
}

Error in .NET 8
{
    "errors": {
        "age": [
            "Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Int32'. Path 'age', line 3, position 15."
        ],
        "person": [
            "The person field is required."
        ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-9df50c9ae2e267f2fe8a525c17162586-7661f82dc052edbd-00"
}


I think you need to set the Age property to a nullable type in .NET 8. int? age, but it will be null instead of 0

That would indeed solve the issue, but my question is why did it work in .NET Framwork ? I have an existing API and want to be sure I am not breaking anything,

Because .NET Core changed a lot of things :) They set their goal on performance and security. It is a new way so... it will break the old way :) You should not try to make the new thing behave the exact way the old way was. There are new rules, try to apply to them. If you really want to behave the old way you can create a custom deserializer/serializer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/migrate-from-newtonsoft?pivots=dotnet-9-0#differences-in-default-behavior

I found this response that might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31750851/8404545

@max , it is a public API. So everyone that is calling us expect the API to behave the exact same way. I can make it nullable to mimic the old behavior. But now I am wondering what else have changed ...
