# Deserializing Json from a stream into a string property

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

In order to reuse an existing code that uses Newtonsoft Json.NET I need to be able to deserialize the whole json content of a stream into a single property of a "BadData" object.

Example:

```
public class BadDataEntity
{
  [Key]
  public int ID { get; set; }

  public string BadData { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a combination of attributes I can add to this class so when I deserialize any Json it goes completley as a string into the BadData property?

Thanks.

Comment: So in other words, you don't really want to deserialize the JSON at all.  If that's the case, you don't need Json.NET.  Just get the contents of the stream as a string and set the property on the object.

Comment: I have a code that deserializes messages from a queue into entities and persist the entities. It will be ideal if I could, using configuration only, use the same process to point to the deadletter queue, use a different entity (BadRecords) and persist the full Json without having to write a separate service.

Answer (score 0):

If for whatever reason you *must* parse this class using Json.NET (rather than simply reading the stream into a string then manually constructing your class from it), you can create a [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) that loads the JSON into a [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) then stores its string value into your `BadDataEntity` class:

```
public class BadDataEntityConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(BadDataEntity).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Note that BadData MUST BE VALID JSON, otherwise this won't work.
        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        var bad = (existingValue as BadDataEntity ?? new BadDataEntity());
        bad.BadData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(token, Formatting.Indented);
        return bad;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var bad = (BadDataEntity)value;
        if (bad.BadData == null)
            writer.WriteNull();
        else
        {
            var token = JToken.Parse(bad.BadData);
            token.WriteTo(writer, serializer.Converters.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the string must contain valid JSON.

Then you can attach the converter to your class like so:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(BadDataEntityConverter))]
public class BadDataEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string BadData { get; set; }
}
```

Or put it in the list of [converters](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Converters.htm), as is shown in the [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) and in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510532/registering-a-custom-jsonconverter-globally-in-json-net).