# Json.Net: Serialize/Deserialize property as a value, not as an object

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

How can I achieve the following JSON representation of Id class when used in another class?

```
class Car
{
    public StringId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class StringId
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

// ---------------------------------------------

// Desired representation
{ "Id": "someId", "Name": "Ford" }

// Default (undesired) representation
{ "Id" : { "Value": "someId" }, "Name": "Ford" }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could add a [`TypeConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx) for `StringId`.  Json.NET will pick up the type converter and use it to convert it from and to a string:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(StringIdConverter))]
class StringId
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

class StringIdConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
            return true;
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(StringId))
            return true;
        return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            return new StringId { Value = (string)value };
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string) && value is StringId)
        {
            return ((StringId)value).Value;
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

If your string representation contains embedded numeric or date/time data, be sure to convert that data using the `culture` passed in rather than the default, current culture.  Json.NET will call the converter with the correct culture, [which is the invariant culture by default](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Culture.htm), thus ensuring the generated JSON files are portable between cultures.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pshMvQ).

Note however that, if you are using .Net Core, support for type converters was only added as of [Json.NET 10.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/10.0.1).  And support for type converters in Json.NET Portable builds is not available as of 10.0.3.

Alternatively, if you don't mind adding Json.NET-specific attributes to your type, you could use a [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm):

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringIdConverter))]
class StringId
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

class StringIdConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(StringId);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        return new StringId { Value = (string)token };
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var id = (StringId)value;
        writer.WriteValue(id.Value);
    }
}
```

You can also set the converter in [global settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510532/registering-a-custom-jsonconverter-globally-in-json-net).

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/daLYOX).

Comment: None of these methods worked for me. I wonder if .NET Core affects the serialization anyhow. I wrote a unit test and what I see in debugger is that non of the Converters' methods are called...

Comment: CORRECTION: I was not very careful in my tests... The JsonConverter does work, but I would prefer the TypeConverter.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko - what version of json.net are you using?  Apparently it didn't work with 8.0.3: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8679.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `ToString` method of the `StringId` class to return the value

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Value;
    }
```

You will need a `TypeConverter` later to deserialize from string to `StringId`

```
public class StringIdConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }


    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            return new StringId(value.ToString());
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

And decorate your `StringId` class with this attribute

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(StringIdConverter))]
public class StringId{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Just my curiosity. Does using a TypeConverter affect serialization performance too seriously?

Comment: I've been using it in production for 3 years and never affected the performance