# Custom JsonConverter not working when using JsonReader instead of JsonSerializer

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a class `Foo` and its `FooConverter` as defined below:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(FooConverter))]
public class Foo
{
    public string Something { get; set; }
}

public class FooConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(((Foo)value).Something);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var str = reader.ReadAsString();
        if (str == null)
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException();
        }    
        // return new Foo {Something = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader)};
        return new Foo {Something = str};
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Foo);
    }
}
```

Serializing works fine. But when deserializing:

```
var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>("\"something\"");
```

it throws `JsonSerializationException` because `reader.ReadAsString` is null.
But I don't understand why it has to be `null`... `reader.ReadAsString` works perfectly find if I'm doing it manually like so:

```
var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader("\"something\""));
var str = reader.ReadAsString(); // str is now `something` NOT null
```

Although I can fix `FooConverter` by using `serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader)` in `ReadJson`, I still want to understand why `reader.ReadAsString` fails in `FooConverter.ReadJson`.

Comment: If you are looking for a `JsonConverter` that can serialize an object as a string primitive, see `StringIdConverter` from [Json.Net: Serialize/Deserialize property as a value, not as an object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40480742/3744182).

Comment: @dbc that's interesting. `JToken.Load(reader)` correctly reads the string. Do you know why reader.ReadAsString() doesn't?

Comment: Yes, adding an answer now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that, according to the [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_ReadAsString.htm), `JsonReader.ReadAsString()`:

> Reads the **next** JSON token from the source as a String.

However, when [`JsonConverter.ReadJson()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_ReadJson.htm) is called, the reader is already positioned on the first JSON token corresponding to the object being deserialized.  Thus, by calling `ReadAsString()` you discard that value and try to read the next token in the stream -- but there is none, so you throw an exception.

Further, At the end of `ReadJson()` your code must have positioned the reader at the last JSON token corresponding to the object being converted.  So, in the case where the JSON is simply a primitive, the reader should not get advanced at all.

A simple way to guarantee that the reader is always correctly positioned by `ReadJson()` is to call [`JToken.Load()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Load.htm).  This always leaves the reader positioned at the end of the token that was loaded.  Afterwards, you can check to see that what was loaded was as expected.  E.g., if the JSON has an object where a string was expected, rather than leaving the reader incorrectly positioned, the converter should throw an exception rather than leave the reader incorrectly positioned.

`StringIdConverter` from *[Json.Net: Serialize/Deserialize property as a value, not as an object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40480742/3744182)* gives an example of this.  You could modify it as follows:

```
public class FooConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (!(token is JValue))
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Token was not a primitive");
        return new Foo { Something = (string)token };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `"\"something\""` is not valid JSON, it's just an escaped string. JSON = JavaScript Object Notation, in which an empty object is defined as `{}`.

An object with state is just a dictionary structure, where keys have values. Your `Foo` type has a property `Something`, which is the key, and it needs to be assigned a value. So try a JSON object like this:

```
{ Something: "a value" }
```

which in C# would be converted like this:

```
var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>("{\"Something\":\"a value\"}");
```

Comment: Yep, this is the problem. I suspect `JsonReader` specifically looks for correctly defined JSON properties.

Comment: @DanielMay then why is JsonReader working fine when I use it manually? (As seen from the question)

Comment: @Dvs I can't use that because I need to manually Deserialize. That's why I used a JsonConverter.

Comment: @WingerSendon can you explain (1) why you need to 'manually' convert JSON (is a bit of a code smell) and (2) why are you trying to do this by inheriting from `JsonConverter`, which is I assume the Newtonsoft.Json type, which will expect valid JSON?

Comment: @Dvs I have a type which is a wrapper over a string (more specifically a "string enum" as seen from the accepted answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424366/c-sharp-string-enums) question). So it need to be converted into a Json string instead of a Json object.
And this object isn't translated directly to json. It's inside another object so it might appear like this in Json: `{"MyStringEnum":"a value"}`  
(2) idk what you mean by that. Strings are converted to json strings. Arrays are converted to json arrays. I want my class to be converted to a json string.