# Why my dull Newtonsoft.Json deserialization code does not work?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following custom `JsonConverter`:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

namespace CSTool.Json
{
    public class TextSpanJsonConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(TextSpan);

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var str = reader.ReadAsString();
            var delim = str.IndexOf('.');
            var start = int.Parse(str.AsSpan(1, delim - 1));
            var end = int.Parse(str.AsSpan(delim + 2, str.Length - delim - 3));
            return TextSpan.FromBounds(start, end);
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

It is supposed to help (de)serialize the following class:

```
using CSTool.Json;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace CSTool.ObjectModel
{
    public class RefLocCacheItem
    {
        public string FilePath { get; private set; }
        [JsonConverter(typeof(TextSpanJsonConverter))]
        public TextSpan TextSpan { get; private set; }
        [JsonConverter(typeof(LinePositionSpanJsonConverter))]
        public LinePositionSpan LinePositionSpan { get; private set; }

        public RefLocCacheItem()
        {
        }
        public RefLocCacheItem(Location o) : this(o.SourceTree.FilePath, o.SourceSpan, o.GetLineSpan().Span)
        {
        }
        public RefLocCacheItem(string filePath, TextSpan textSpan, LinePositionSpan linePositionSpan)
        {
            FilePath = filePath;
            TextSpan = textSpan;
            LinePositionSpan = linePositionSpan;
        }
    }
}
```

The deserialization code is:

```
cached = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<uint, List<RefLocCacheItem>>>(File.ReadAllText(cacheFile));
```

The respective serialization code is:

```
File.WriteAllText(cacheFile, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cached, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
```

And here is a sample json file:

```
{
  "100666494": [],
  "100666517": [],
  "67111627": [
    {
      "FilePath": "c:\xyz\\tip\\MySourceFile.cs",
      "TextSpan": "[105331..105379)",
      "LinePositionSpan": "(2379,51)-(2379,99)"
    }
  ],
  "67111628": [
    {
      "FilePath": "c:\xyz\\tip\\MySourceFile.cs",
      "TextSpan": "[136762..136795)",
      "LinePositionSpan": "(2953,30)-(2953,63)"
    }
  ],
  "100666534": []
}
```

So, as you can see, serialization works fine. However, the deserialization code never invokes the converter's `ReadJson` function. In fact, it does not work at all! There is no failure, but the returned dictionary contains `RefLocCacheItem`s with `null` file paths and empty text spans:

[image]

I used Json.Net many times in the past and I don't understand what am I doing wrong now.

I use the latest version - 13.0.1, but I checked a few older versions - same thing. So, it is my fault, but where?

### Clarification edit

The `FilePath` property is not deserialized. And it has nothing to do with the converter. And the converter - the `ReadJson` method is not even called!

Comment: I haven't debugged your code yet, but you probably want `reader.Value` not `reader.ReadAsString()`.  For why see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46025896/3744182) to [Custom JsonConverter not working when using JsonReader instead of JsonSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46024882/3744182).  In fact this may be a duplicate, agree?

Comment: @dbc - Thanks for responding. The problem is that FilePath is not deserialized either! The `ReadJson` is not even called!

Comment: All of your properties have private setters.  Try adding `[JsonProperty]` to the properties, or else make them public.

Comment: Well once the `JsonReader` is mis-positioned all sorts values are going to get dropped.

Comment: @dbc - it is never called at all.

Comment: @BrianRogers - damn, this is it. I was 100% sure it does not matter for Json.Net. Please, arrange as the answer so I could credit you.

Comment: @dbc - now that it is called, I can see you were right too. But the true reason - private setters. I am still shocked, since I was sure it does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your properties have private setters.  As such, Json.Net will treat them as read-only.  You can either make the setter public, or, if you wish to keep the setters private, you can add a `[JsonProperty]` attribute to the property to tell Json.Net that it is OK to use the private setter:

```
[JsonProperty]
public string FilePath { get; private set; }

[JsonProperty, JsonConverter(typeof(TextSpanJsonConverter))]
public TextSpan TextSpan { get; private set; }
```