# Json.NET - Serialize generic type wrapper without property name

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a generic type that wraps a single primitive type to give it value equality semantics

```
public class ValueObject<T>
{
    public T Value { get; }
    public ValueObject(T value) => Value = value;

    // various other equality members etc...
}
```

It is used like:

```
public class CustomerId : ValueObject<Guid>
{
    public CustomerId(Guid value) : base(value) { }
}

public class EmailAddress : ValueObject<string>
{
    public EmailAddress(string value) : base(value) { }
}
```

The issue is when serializing a type like:

```
public class Customer
{
    public CustomerId Id { get; }
    public EmailAddress Email { get; }

    public Customer(CustomerId id, EmailAddress email) 
    { 
        Id = id;
        Email = email;
    }
}
```

Each object the inherits from `ValueObject<T>` is wrapped in a `Value` property (as expected). For example

```
var customerId = new CustomerId(Guid.NewGuid());
var emailAddress = new EmailAddress("some@email.com");

var customer = new Customer(customerId, emailAddress);

var customerAsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() 
})
```

Results in

```
{
  "id": {
    "value": "f5ce21a5-a0d1-4888-8d22-6f484794ac7c"
  },
  "email": {
    "value": "some@email.com"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to write a custom `JsonConverter` so the the `Value` property is excluded for types subclassing `ValueObject<T>` so that the above example would output

```
{
  "id": "f5ce21a5-a0d1-4888-8d22-6f484794ac7c",
  "email": "some@email.com"
}
```

I would prefer to have a single `JsonConverter` that can handle all `ValueObject<T>` rather than having to define a separate `JsonConverter` for each `ValueObject<T>` subclass

My first attempt was

```
public class ValueObjectOfTConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private static readonly Type ValueObjectGenericType = typeof(ValueObject<>);
    private static readonly string ValuePropertyName = nameof(ValueObject<object>.Value);

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) =>
        IsSubclassOfGenericType(objectType, ValueObjectGenericType);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // converts "f5ce21a5-a0d1-4888-8d22-6f484794ac7c" => "value": "f5ce21a5-a0d1-4888-8d22-6f484794ac7c"
        var existingJsonWrappedInValueProperty = new JObject(new JProperty(ValuePropertyName, JToken.Load(reader)));
        return existingJsonWrappedInValueProperty.ToObject(objectType, serializer);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // to implement
    }

    private static bool IsSubclassOfGenericType(Type typeToCheck, Type openGenericType)
    {
        while (typeToCheck != null && typeToCheck != typeof(object))
        {
            var cur = typeToCheck.IsGenericType ? typeToCheck.GetGenericTypeDefinition() : typeToCheck;
            if (openGenericType == cur) return true;

            typeToCheck = typeToCheck.BaseType;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, you could add a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) like the ones shown in [Json.Net: Serialize/Deserialize property as a value, not as an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480489/3744182).  But using a converter can sometimes interfere with polymorphism and [`TypeNameHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm).  Are you ever using `ValueObject<T>` in cases where you want to preserve type information for primitives?  And why only for types subclassing `ValueObject<T>`?

Comment: Or, is your difficulty with writing the [`JsonConverter.CanConvert` method](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_CanConvert.htm)?

Comment: I have updated the question. I would prefer to not have to write a custom converter for each subclass.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) similar to the ones shown in *[Json.Net: Serialize/Deserialize property as a value, not as an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480489/3744182)*.  However, since `ValueObject<T>` does not have a non-generic method to get and set the `Value` as an object, you will need to use reflection.

Here's one approach:

```
class ValueConverter : JsonConverter
{
    static Type GetValueType(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType
            .BaseTypesAndSelf()
            .Where(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ValueObject<>))
            .Select(t => t.GetGenericArguments()[0])
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return GetValueType(objectType) != null;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // You need to decide whether a null JSON token results in a null ValueObject<T> or 
        // an allocated ValueObject<T> with a null Value.
        if (reader.SkipComments().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var valueType = GetValueType(objectType);
        var value = serializer.Deserialize(reader, valueType);

        // Here we assume that every subclass of ValueObject<T> has a constructor with a single argument, of type T.
        return Activator.CreateInstance(objectType, value);
    }

    const string ValuePropertyName = nameof(ValueObject<object>.Value);

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var contract = (JsonObjectContract)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(value.GetType());
        var valueProperty = contract.Properties.Where(p => p.UnderlyingName == ValuePropertyName).Single();
        // You can simplify this to .Single() if ValueObject<T> has no other properties:
        // var valueProperty = contract.Properties.Single();
        serializer.Serialize(writer, valueProperty.ValueProvider.GetValue(value));
    }
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader SkipComments(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment && reader.Read())
            ;
        return reader;
    }
}

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> BaseTypesAndSelf(this Type type)
    {
        while (type != null)
        {
            yield return type;
            type = type.BaseType;
        }
    }
}
```

You could then apply the converter directly to `ValueType<T>` like so:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ValueConverter))]
public class ValueObject<T>
{
    // Remainder unchanged
}
```

Or apply it in settings instead:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new ValueConverter() },
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() 
};
var customerAsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

Working sample .Net fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/smioqg).

Alternatively, you might consider adding a non-generic method to access the value as an `object`, e.g. like so:

```
public interface IHasValue
{
    object GetValue(); // A method rather than a property to ensure the non-generic value is never serialized directly.
}

public class ValueObject<T> : IHasValue
{
    public T Value { get; }
    public ValueObject(T value) => Value = value;

    // various other equality members etc...

    #region IHasValue Members

    object IHasValue.GetValue() => Value;

    #endregion
}
```

With this addition, [`WriteJson()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_WriteJson.htm) becomes much simpler:

```
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, ((IHasValue)value).GetValue());
    }
```

Working sample .Net fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/avkz5o).

Notes:

- `ReadJson()` assumes that every subclass of `Value<T>` has a public constructor taking a single argument of type `T`.
- Applying the converter directly to `ValueType<T>` using [`[JsonConverter(typeof(ValueConverter))]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm) will have slightly better performance, since [`CanConvert`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_CanConvert.htm) need never get called.  See *[Performance Tips: JsonConverters](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#JsonConverters)* for details.
- You need to decide how to handle a `null` JSON token.  Should it result in a null `ValueType<T>`, or an allocated `ValueType<T>` with a null `Value`?
- In the second version of `ValueType<T>` I implemented `IHasValue.GetValue()` explicitly to discourage its use in cases where an instance of `ValueType<T>` is used in statically typed code.
- If you really only want to apply the converter to *types **subclassing** `ValueObject<T>`* and not `ValueObject<T>` itself, in `GetValueType(Type objectType)` add a call to `.Skip(1)`:

  ```
  static Type GetValueType(Type objectType)
  {
      return objectType
          .BaseTypesAndSelf()
          .Skip(1) // Do not apply the converter to ValueObject<T> when not subclassed
          .Where(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ValueObject<>))
          .Select(t => t.GetGenericArguments()[0])
          .FirstOrDefault();
  }
  ```

  And then apply the converter in `JsonSerializerSettings.Converters` rather than directly to `ValueObject<T>`.

Comment: Not knowing much about custom serialization, my first attempt was to manipulate the JObject directly to avoid reflection.

This is where I got to with `ReadJson` which seemed to work but I had issues with `WriteJson` .. Is this alternative worth considering?

`
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var existingJsonWrappedInValueProperty = new JObject(new JProperty("Value"), JToken.Load(reader)));
    return existingJsonWrappedInValueProperty.ToObject(objectType, serializer);
}
`

Comment: @kimsagro - not sure, I'd need to see a full, properly formatted example.  The `JObject` is an intermediate representation however, which the above converter avoids creating.

Comment: @kimsagro - OK, so what is your question then?  Is it *[How can I] serialize a generic type wrapper without the property name* or is it, *How can I fix my current `ValueObjectOfTConverter`*?  If the second, what is not working?  Is it just that you need to write `WriteJson()`?  If so, you should be able to use the one from my answer.