# json.net serialize derived as generic base

Tags: c#, json.net, c#-7.0

(this issue stems from trying to serialize/deserialize LikeType classes to JSON - https://github.com/kleinwareio/LikeType)

I have:

```
    public abstract class LikeType<T>
    {
      public T Value;
      // ....

      // how to tell json.net to serialize/deserialize classes deriving
      // from this like it would T ???
    }

    public class Name : LikeType<string>  { 
      public Name(string s) : base(s) { } 
      // does not add any properties
    }

    void test()
    {
      var name = new Name("john");
      var jobj = new JObject();
      try
      {
        jobj.Add("key", new JObject(name));
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         !Exeption !
         e = {System.ArgumentException: Could not determine JSON object type for type Name. at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue.GetValueType(Nullable`1 current, Object value) at  Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.CreateFromContent(Object content)
      }
    }
```

How can I specify that all classes deriving from `LikeType<T>` will be serialized/ deserialized to JSON with Json.Net in the same way `T` would?

(in this case, Json.Net should serialize/deserialize Name in the same way it would a string)

Comment: This makes little sense to me. Could you provide some examples where you serialize different instances of `LikeType<T>`? What should the output be when the type argument is `double` or `DateTime`?

Comment: exactly the same as Json.Net would serialize double or DateTime. I want to serialize LikeType<t> in the default way for T

Comment: That works out of the box, just do `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Name("test"));` I honestly don't understand what your actual *issue* is here. What does not behave as you expect it to?

Comment: Can you please post an [mcve], the json it produces, and what you want to change about it? I don't understand what you mean by "like it would T". Json.Net **does** serialize generic types, **just as it serializes T**, can you please clarify exactly what the problem is?

Comment: thx, I added test code showing the exception I get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to "forward" `LikeType<T>` serialization, treating this like an invisible wrapper type. This assumption is crucial to my solution.

I'd suggest using `JsonConverter` implementation to do that. There is a very similar post here: [Json.NET - Serialize generic type wrapper without property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50313978/json-net-serialize-generic-type-wrapper-without-property-name)

I've adapted the example to your case. This is the adapted approach:

```
class LikeTypeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    static Type GetValueType(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType
            .BaseTypesAndSelf()
            .Where(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(LikeType<>))
            .Select(t => t.GetGenericArguments()[0])
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return GetValueType(objectType) != null;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // You need to decide whether a null JSON token results in a null LikeType<T> or 
        // an allocated LikeType<T> with a null Value.
        if (reader.SkipComments().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var valueType = GetValueType(objectType);
        var value = serializer.Deserialize(reader, valueType);

        // Here we assume that every subclass of LikeType<T> has a constructor with a single argument, of type T.
        return Activator.CreateInstance(objectType, value);
    }

    const string ValuePropertyName = "Value";// nameof(LikeType<object>.Value); // in C#6+

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var contract = (JsonObjectContract)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(value.GetType());
        var valueProperty = contract.Properties.Single(p => p.UnderlyingName == ValuePropertyName);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, valueProperty.ValueProvider.GetValue(value));
    }
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader SkipComments(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment && reader.Read())
        {
        }

        return reader;
    }
}

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> BaseTypesAndSelf(this Type type)
    {
        while (type != null)
        {
            yield return type;
            type = type.BaseType;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this as an attribute on `LikeType<T>` declaration if you want to include this in your library:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(LikeTypeConverter))]
public abstract class LikeType<T> { ... }
```

Or you can use the converter when necessary, modifying `JsonSerializerSettings.Converters` collection:

```
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Converters = { new LikeTypeConverter() },
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
    };
    var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

I've also created a [working dotnetfiddle sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nppc6y) for demonstration (also adapting the one from linked post).

Comment: thank you !! I cannot get it to work with the attribute :( I added a test to your fiddle here https://dotnetfiddle.net/mo0Imh what's wrong ?

Comment: ah I got it, I needed JObject.FromObject

Comment: question, in .Where(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(LikeType<>)) - can we have a way to not specify the class there (LikeType<>) so we can have a general way to serialize classes that proxy another class through a Value property ?

Comment: @kofifus Possibly. But you'd need another way to extract the Type of that Value property. Maybe you could instead do `objectType.GetProperty("Value")?.PropertyType` if you're always looking for that single property. It can be a dangerous pattern, because this'd also work for all Nullable<T> types. :)

Comment: I did find a way and also added using an empty ctor if the other one is not there see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51295920/460084

Answer (score 0):

One way of controlling what most serializers serialize is using the [Serializable attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.serializableattribute) and implement the [ISerializable interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable).