# Custom JSON.Net serializer for generic classes

Tags: c#, generics, json.net

Consider the following program (please ignore that encryption doesn't really encrypt anything, it is not relevant for the question):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace InterfaceSerialize
{
    public class PersonDemographicsSerializer: JsonConverter
    {
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var pd = value as PersonDemographics;
            serializer.Serialize(writer, pd.Age.ToString("X")); // Convert int age to hex string
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return typeof(PersonDemographics).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
        }
    }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(PersonDemographicsSerializer))]
    public class PersonDemographics
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public PersonDemographics pd { get; set; }
        public IEncrypted<string> NationalID { get; set; }
        public IEncrypted<int> Income { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IEncrypted<T>
    {
        T DecryptedData { get; }

        string EncryptedData { get; }
    }

    //[DataContract]
    //[JsonConverter(typeof(EncryptedSerializer))]
    public class Encrypted<T> : IEncrypted<T>
    {
        public string EncryptedData { get; set; }

        public T DecryptedData { get; set; }

        public Encrypted(T input, string password)
        {
            DecryptedData = input;
            EncryptedData = input.ToString() + password;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string password = "-ABCD5678";

            Person p = new Person { PersonId = 100,
                pd = new PersonDemographics { Age = 15, FirstName = "Joe" },
                NationalID = new Encrypted<string>("49804389043", password),
                Income = new Encrypted<int>(50000, password)
            };
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p);
        }
    }
}
```

This generates following JSON:

```
{
  "PersonId": 100,
  "pd": "F",
  "NationalID": {
    "EncryptedData": "49804389043-ABCD5678",
    "DecryptedData": "49804389043"
  },
  "Income": {
    "EncryptedData": "50000-ABCD5678",
    "DecryptedData": 50000
  }
}
```

I figured out how to implement custom serializer (PersonDemographicsSerializer) for the "regular" class. However, I just can't figure out how to do the same for the generic class.

Desired JSON output should only include DecryptedData property for the values of **NationalID** and **Income** and should look like this:

```
{
  "PersonId": 100,
  "pd": "F",
  "NationalID": "49804389043",
  "Income": 50000
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, why don't you just convert your object to a new object with the properties you want and serialize that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Json.net serialize only certain properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50974672/json-net-serialize-only-certain-properties)

Comment: [How can I encrypt selected properties when serializing my objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29196809) may help here.

Comment: Found solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50313978/json-net-serialize-generic-type-wrapper-without-property-name