# Serialize class to single string

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I want to serialize and deserialize a custom class so that it behaves like a simple enum.

For example:

```
public enum Channel
{
   EMail,
   Telephone
}
```

Gives the following Json-Representation:

```
{
    "Channel": "EMail"
}
```

My current approach:

```
[Serializable]
public sealed class Channel : ISerializable
{
    public static readonly Channel Email = new Channel("Email");
    public static readonly Channel Telephone = new Channel("Telephone");

    public string Key { get; private set; }

    //// Deserialization
    private Channel(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Key = (string)info.GetValue(nameof(Channel), typeof(string));
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue(nameof(Channel), Key);
    }
}
```

But this brings up the following json-representation:

```
{
  "Channel":{"Channel":"Email"}
}
```

So I want to get rid of the "complex structure" of the class. In the context of serialization it should behave like an enum or string. How can I achieve that behavior?
All in all I want to get rid of the encapsulation in the json-representation.

Comment: Did not understand your intentions. Do you want to get rid of the encapsulating "Channel" json node and leave only "Channell" : "Email"?

Comment: Rather than using `ISerializable`, use a `TypeConverter` or a `JsonConverter`.  See [Json.Net: Serialize/Deserialize property as a value, not as an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480489).