# Serialize class that provides ToString()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-2.2

Suppose I have some class that defines `ToString()`:

```
class Person {
  public override string ToString() { /* ... */ }
}
```

And suppose an instance is contained in some model:

```
public Person Person { get; }
```

Then it is serialized like this:

```
"person": {
  "value": "Foo Bar"
}
```

But what I expected was this:

```
"person": "Foo Bar"
```

Can I do this somehow, or must I use a custom converter?

---

UPDATE

No this is not a dupe of that linked question. That shows how to do two-way conversion to/from a type. I want to do one-way conversion, given my type already has a `ToString` method - i.e. serialization only, not deserialization.

The question is not how to write a type converter - it is whether this one-way serialization is possible without a type converter.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Json.Net: Serialize/Deserialize property as a value, not as an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480489/3744182), agree?

Comment: @dbc Not a dupe, see update.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this on a project, and the only thing my team came to, was having to write a type converter.

Answer (score 0):

I want a one-way conversion which relies on my type's `ToString()` overload. This is for data serialized on the server and used in a REST response.

This is what I did:

```
public class StringConverter : JsonConverter {

  public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
    return true;
  }

  public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
    throw new NotSupportedException("This one-way converter cannot be used for deserialization.");
  }

  public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
    writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
  }

}
```

Used like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringConverter))]
public Person Person { get; }   // assumes Person has overloaded ToString()
```

And the serialized result is this:

```
"person": "Foo Bar"
```

(instead of `"person": { "value": "Foo Bar" }`.)

Maybe a better name is `ToStringSerializer` or `OneWayStringConverter`.