# Implicitly serialize and deserialize a class to and from a string

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a class that is implicitly convertible from a string and explicitly convertible from a string. It is not a string, though, and I don't want to replace locations in code with a string, just for the sake of convenience.

When I want to serialize or deserialize an object containing a property that uses this type, I want it to be treated like a string. I know, I could just write a converter (in my case a Json.NET converter), but I would prefer the serialization to be implicit and without any attribute decorations when defining a property of this type.

Is there a possibility to make it easy for the serializer and just get a string from the class when serializing and create an object of the class with the string value inside when deserializing?

This is the code of the class:

```
public class StringClass
{
    private string value;

    public StringClass(string s)
    {
        Validate(s);
        value = s;
    }

    private void Validate(string value)
    {
        // Some validation happening here, throwing an exception if the input does not match
    }

    public static implicit operator StringClass(string s) => new(s);

    public static explicit operator string(StringClass sc) => sc.value;

    public override int GetHashCode() => value.GetHashCode();

    public override string ToString() => value;
}
```

An example for a class where this is in use:

**C#**

```
public class TestClass
{
    public StringClass Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Json**

```
{
    "id": "123456789abcdef",
    "name": "username"
}
```

Things I thought about doing:

1. Implementing the [ISerializable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable?view=net-5.0) interface. But I think this works only when serializing, not when deserializing.
2. Writing a converter but instead of applying it to the property, apply it to the class itself somehow (if that's possible).

I am totally fine with "there is no other option, write a converter that needs to be applied to the property", but I want to know if there is an alternative that allows me to omit the whole attribute-on-property-thing and just make it implicit.

Comment: 1. [ISerializable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable?view=net-5.0), see the example. It serialize and deserialize.

Comment: 2. You can add the converter in serializer's settings (no need decoration or attribute).

Comment: Ah, thanks, I totally forgot the second one! And I never used ISerializable, I didn't know it works both ways. Perfect, thanks!

Comment: `ISerializable` lets you serialize your class with manually created key/value pairs, but you want to serialize it as a simple string, so I don't think that will work.  Since you mention using Json.NET, see [Json.Net: Serialize/Deserialize property as a value, not as an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480489/3744182). One way or another you will need a `JsonConverter` or `TypeConverter`, Json.NET won't pick up the implicit operator.

Comment: Or I suppose if you really wanted to you could create a custom contract resolver that picks up on the implicit conversions from and to string, and applies an appropriate converter.  Is that what you want?

Comment: So far I managed to do it using a converter and applying it to the class itself. I didn't know that was possible.

Comment: @MaxPlay - is that good enough then?  If so shall we close this off as a duplicate of [Json.Net: Serialize/Deserialize property as a value, not as an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480489/3744182)?

Comment: @dbc Sure, it's basically a duplicate of the linked question.