# WEB API to return Nested Array JSON Result C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

Hi Request your help in Below Scenario.
I have a Requirement where in I want to return Response JSON from DotNet WEB API As below.

```
{ "Status":"OK", "Series":[["GREEN",40.5],["RED",12.8],["YELLOW",12.8]] }
```

Below are my Code Sample and Output.

```
public class Response
{
public string Status {get;set;}
public List<SampleData> Series {get;set;}
}

public class SampleData
{
public string ColorCode{get;set;}
public double ColorVal{get;set;}
}
```

API Get Method

```
public Response Get()
        {
            Response Objresponse = new Response();
             Objresponse.Status ="OK";
             List<SampleData> _sampleList = new List<SampleData>();
             _sampleList.Add(new SampleData{ ColorCode="GREEN", ColorVal=40.5});
             _sampleList.Add(new SampleData{ ColorCode="RED",ColorVal=12.8});
             _sampleList.Add(new SampleData{ ColorCode="YELLOW",ColorVal=12.8});
             Objresponse.Series = _sampleList;
            return Objresponse;
        }
```

JSON Output which is returned

```
{
"Status":"OK",
"Series":[
{"ColorCode":"GREEN","ColorVal":40.5},
{"ColorCode":"RED","ColorVal":12.8},
{"ColorCode":"YELLOW","ColorVal":12.8}
]
}
```

Request your help to return the output as per my requirement.
Thank you.......

Comment: You can either change the List<SampleData> into a Dictionary<string, double> or a list<string, double>. That way it should serialize the way you want it to. If you don't want to do that look up how to implement a  `JsonConverter` create one for the class type `Response` and make sure the server globally adds this as one of Json.Net Converters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to create a custom JsonConverter and transform your response inside to your required format:

```
public class ResponseConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(Response);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Response originalResponse = (Response)value;
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName(nameof(originalResponse.Status));
        writer.WriteValue(originalResponse.Status);
        writer.WritePropertyName(nameof(originalResponse.Series));
        writer.WriteStartArray();            
        foreach (var val in originalResponse.Series)
        {
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            writer.WriteValue(val.ColorCode);
            writer.WriteValue(val.ColorVal);
            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }
        writer.WriteEndArray();
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

Then, you can decorate your `Response` class with a special attribute to denote that it should be serialized with this converter:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ResponseConverter))]
public class Response
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public List<SampleData> Series { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `Then, you have to decorate your Response class` there also is the option of adding the converter globally. As Shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19512471/8579225)

Comment: @Drag0nvil True, that's another possible option.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response. I am getting below response after trying the solution suggested.  {
    "Status": "OK",
    "Series": {
        "GREEN": 40.5,
        "RED": 12.8,
        "YELLOW": 12.8
    }
} by any chance is it possible to make series value like this "Series":[["GREEN",40.5],["RED",12.8],["YELLOW",12.8]]

Comment: Sorry for that, I missed the square brackets (it's still early for me here :) ).So basically you want an array of arrays, where the inner arrays have a string and a float for elements. I have to say, it's a little strange, but I'm not the one to judge. See my edited answer, hopefully it works as required now.