# How to define string to object/dictionary in JSON

Tags: c#, json

I create a class for define my request, I don't get the accepted JSON string

I define this object:

```
public class Request
{
    public Var_Args[] var_args { get; set; }
}

public class  Var_Args
{
    public object title { get; set; }
    public object owner { get; set; }
}
```

when I convert it to json, I get the following string:

```
{"requests":[{"var_args":[{"title":"Test","owner":"skaner"}]}]}
```

how can I define the class, for get the accepted json string:

```
{"requests":[{"var_args":[{"title":"Test"},{"owner":"skaner"}]}]}
```

Comment: is there a source code error in your sample:
{"requests":[{""var_args":[{"title":"Test"},{"owner":"skaner"}]}]}
should be
{"requests":[{"var_args":[{"title":"Test"},{"owner":"skaner"}]}]}

Comment: When I send the first json string I get the error:
{
    "responses": [
        {
            "tran_id": "unknown",
            "UUID": "",
            "status": "error",
            "messages": [
                {
                    "errorcode": 20001,
                    "errorsummary": "Incorrect JSON Format",
                    "errordetail": "Incorrect JSON Format"
                }
            ],
            "result_params": {},
            "result_table": []
        }
    ]
}

Comment: it's my mistake, I didn't copy the code right. fix, still I have a Q...

Comment: Add JsonPropertyAttribute to your property and you can define whatever name you want.

Comment: are you using json.net?

Comment: Tobias: I want to define a general format converter for all my class, I don't want to define attribute for every field

Comment: ngeksyo: this is my serialize code: string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testCase);

Comment: Tobias: maybe JsonPropertyAttribute it's match, i will investigation it, do you have an example for me?

Comment: You can also hock into json-(de)serialization and define converters or their behaviour. Have a look at `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom JSON converter that can serialize every property of an object (of a known type) into a different JSON object.

```
public class PropertyAsObjectConverter : JsonConverter
{
   private readonly Type[] _types;

   public PropertyAsObjectConverter(params Type[] types)
   {
      _types = types;
   }

   public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
   {
      return _types.Any(t => t == objectType);
   }

   public override bool CanRead
   {
      get { return false; }
   }

   public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }

   public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
   {
      var properties = value.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance);
      foreach(var property in properties)
      {
         var name = property.Name;
         var attrs = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute));
         if(attrs != null)
         {
            if (attrs.FirstOrDefault() is JsonPropertyAttribute attr)
               name = attr.PropertyName;
         }

         writer.WriteStartObject();
         writer.WritePropertyName(name);
         serializer.Serialize(writer, property.GetValue(value));
         writer.WriteEndObject();
      }
   }
}
```

This implements only the serialization, but you can extend it to support deserialization too. You can also extend it to serialize fields should you need that.

You can then define your classes as follows. Notice that I am using `JsonPropertyAttribute` here to specify the name in the serialized JSON.

```
public class Content
{
   [JsonProperty("requests")]
   public Request Value { get; set; }
}

public class Request
{
   [JsonProperty("var_args")]
   public VarArgs[] Arguments { get; set; }
}

public class VarArgs
{
   [JsonProperty("title")]
   public object Title { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("owner")]
   public object Owner { get; set; }
}
```

This is how you can use it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var request = new Content()
   {
      Value = new Request()
      {
         Arguments = new VarArgs[]
         {
            new VarArgs()
            {
               Title = "Test",
               Owner = "Skaner",
            }
         }
      }
   };

   var text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
      request,
      Formatting.None, 
      new PropertyAsObjectConverter(typeof(VarArgs)));

   Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

The output for this sample is the one you expect:

```
{"requests":{"var_args":[{"title":"Test"},{"owner":"Skaner"}]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) like the below.
It takes the `Var_Args` object and splits it in two different `JObject` which correspond to two different JSON objects.

```
public class VarArgsConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var obj = (JObject)JToken.FromObject(value);

        var objTitle = new JObject();
        objTitle.Add("title", obj.GetValue("title"));

        var objOwner = new JObject();
        objOwner.Add("owner", obj.GetValue("owner"));

        objTitle.WriteTo(writer);
        objOwner.WriteTo(writer);
    }


    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanRead is false. The type will skip the converter.");
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Var_Args);
    }
}

public class Wrapper
{
    [JsonProperty("requests")]
    public Request Requests { get; set; }
}

public class Request
{
    public Var_Args[] var_args { get; set; }
}

public class Var_Args
{
    public object title { get; set; }
    public object owner { get; set; }
}
```

Then use it:

```
var wrapper = new Wrapper();

var request = new Request();
request.var_args = new Var_Args[] {
    new Var_Args(){ title = "Test", owner = "skaner" },
    new Var_Args(){ title = "Test2", owner = "skaner2" }
};

wrapper.Requests = request;

var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wrapper, new VarArgsConverter());
```

**Output**

```
{"requests":{"var_args":[{"title":"Test"},{"owner":"skaner"},{"title":"Test2"},{"owner":"skaner2"}]}}
```

**Note**: I'm using the `Wrapper` class just to produce the requested JSON.

If you don't want to specify the converter each time, you can register your converter globally. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19512471/7772490) which explains how you can do that. So, the serializer will use your custom `JsonConverter` every time you try to serialize a `Var_Args` object.

If you register the `JsonConvert` globally you can use:

```
var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wrapper);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Reflection` to redefine `Var_Args` as an implementation of the  `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,object>>` interface by adding two methods to the class:

```
public class Var_Args : IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,object>>
{
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<Dictionary<string,object>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var Properties = GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        foreach (var Property in Properties)
        {
            var Entry = new Dictionary<string,object>();
            Entry.Add(Property.Name, Property.GetValue(this));
            yield return Entry;
        }
    }

    public object title { get; set; }
    public object owner { get; set; }
}
```

While `Reflection` may be regarded as slow, there is a technique you can use to statically compile an `IEnumerable` at runtime so that the reflection only occurs once for the definition of the class, like this:

```
public class Var_Args : IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,object>>
{
    private struct PropertyList<T>
    {
        public static readonly List<Func<T,Dictionary<string,object>>> PropertyGetters;

        static PropertyList()
        {
            PropertyGetters = new List<Func<T,Dictionary<string,object>>>();
            var Properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            foreach (var Property in Properties)
            {
                var Args = new [] { Expression.Parameter(typeof(T)) };
                var Key = Property.Name;
                var Value = Expression.Property(Args[0], Property);
                Func<T,object> Get = Expression.Lambda<Func<T,object>>(Value, Args).Compile();

                PropertyGetters.Add(obj =>
                {
                    var entry = new Dictionary<string,object>();
                    entry.Add(Key, Get(obj));
                    return entry;
                });
            }
        }
    }

    protected static IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,object>> GetPropertiesAsEntries<T>(T obj)
    {
        return PropertyList<T>.PropertyGetters.Select(f => f(obj));
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<Dictionary<string,object>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetPropertiesAsEntries(this).GetEnumerator();
    }

    public object title { get; set; }
    public object owner { get; set; }
}
```