# Json.NET - How to serialize property that value can be c# keyword?

Tags: c#, serialization, enums, json.net

I receive a JSON text from an API call, and one of the properties can have a string value that sometimes equals to `false`, this is where the problem begins. Since the value type must be `ExternalDownload`, when I get `false` value I need to make the `ExternalDownload` equals to `null`.
**JSON example**
http://coub.com/api/v2/coubs/20971754
**Data model**

```
public partial class ExternalDownload
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public DownloadType Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public Uri Url { get; set; }
}
```

**Enum**

```
public enum DownloadType
{
    Youtube,
    Vimeo,
    Vk,
    Instagram,
    Vine,
    Wimp,
    Facebook,
    Odnoklassniki,
    Funnyordie,
    Carambatv,
    CollegeHumor,
    LiveLeak,
    Dailymotion,
    TetTv
}
```

**Exception**

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value
>   False to type 'Coub.Net.Objects.ExternalDownload'. Path
>   'external_download', line 1, position 3093.'
>
> > ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.Boolean to
> >     Coub.Net.Objects.ExternalDownload.

Comment: Have you tried a [custom Json converter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm)?

Comment: @AndersonMatos Not yet, but I try now.

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] that includes the JSON you are trying to deserialize, and your target c# model?  Is the JSON value `"False"` or `false` (without quotes)?  If it's a string then `EnumMember` should just work, but if it's a JSON Boolean primitive (see http://json.org/ for details on the difference) then you will need to do something manual.

Comment: @dbc I checked it again and it is `false` and not `"false"`, now I understand the problem.

Comment: I was wrong, not the `enum` has the `false` value but the `ExternalDownload`.

Comment: @AndersonMatos If you post your comment as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: @NoelNemeth - I'm not sure I understand your problem any more.  Are you saying that the value of `ExternalDownload.Type` is `false`, or are you saying that the value of `ExternalDownload` itself is `false`?  A sample of the JSON in question would sure help to clarify.

Comment: @dbc When I first looked at it I thought that `ExternalDownload.Type` would get a false value but later I realized that `ExternalDownload` got a false value. This is why I edited my question. By the way my problem was solved by Custom Converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom converter to work with specific types and as a workaround this issue. This will also enable you to provide custom conversion to other types, not just your enum.

Take a look into `Newtonsoft.Json` docs about this here: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm

Bellow is a sample (from their website):

```
public class VersionConverter : JsonConverter<Version>
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Version value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
    }

    public override Version ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Version existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string s = (string)reader.Value;

        return new Version(s);
    }
}
```

You might use it directly on your code, on `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` overrides that receive the custom converter, or you can register it globally, as shown on this other SO answer: [Registering a custom JsonConverter globally in Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510532/registering-a-custom-jsonconverter-globally-in-json-net)

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum Test
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "True")]
    @true,
    @false
}


class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Test a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>("\"true\"");
        Console.WriteLine(a); //true
    }
}
```

It will work if the value is a string. I.E. `"false"` instead of `false`.

If its later case then you might have to serialize it as string and then do the conversion